# Angular JS Error: $compile:tpload: Failed to load template:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

So I am trying to load the template in my directive. This directive is reusable. But I am failing to load the template. I have had other templates which are loaded and work properly.

The **error** that I am getting is :

```
GET /ClassificationToolkitForGrails/classificationviewer.html 404 (Not Found) angular.js:8521
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: classificationviewer.html
```

The **javascript** file containing the directive:

```
/**
 * 
 */
var classificationViewModule = angular.module('ald.classificationview',[]);

classificationViewModule.factory('classificationAPI',function(){
    return {
        getClassification:function($http, artifactId){
            //TODO add URL
            var url = "/Classification/getInfo?artifactId="+artifactId
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            });
        }
    };
});

/*classificationViewModule.controller('testclassification',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("/Classification/getInfo?artifactId=6450").success(function(data){
        $scope.classification = data;       
    })
}]);*/

classificationViewModule.directive('classificationview', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {

        },
        controller: function ($scope, $http, classificationAPI) {

            classificationAPI.getClassification($http).success(function(data,status){               
                //TODO
                $scope.artifactClassification = data;
            }).error(function(data,status){
                if (404==status){
                    alert("no text");
                } else {
                    alert("bad stuff!");
                }
            });            
        },
        //TODO add template url
        templateUrl: "classificationviewer.html"
    };
});
```

The **template** file :

```
<div>

Hello world

{{artifactClassification}}


</div>
```

The **index.html** file :

```
<

!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Classification Toolkit for Grails</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('classtoolkitApp', [
            'ald.classificationview'
        ]).controller('index', function ($scope) {
        });
    </script>

    <asset:javascript src="ald/classificationview/classificationview.js"/>
</head>
<body >

<div ng-app="classtoolkitApp" ng-controller="index">   

    classification
    <classificationview artifactId=6450/>   

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: True that, mind you that templateUrl needs a path from the root of your app.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. So the template is in a plugin which is used by this project.

Comment: Yes and note that angular is searching for the .html file at the root of your webapp. If you placed the plugin in a folder somewhere you need to specify the whole path from the root. Say /common/directives/someplugin/classificationviewer.html.

Comment: @KaranShah you can also put the template html into an `ng-template` script tag with same ID as templateUrl. If angular finds it there, it won't make ajax request to get it

Comment: I would do that, but I am not sure why this wont work. It worked for all other templates like the hierarchy/document...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: well I did since it was more than a year ago. Unfortunately i dont remember anything about it now

Answer (score 6):

Following are the possible solution
1. check for the correct path. Check the network tab whether you are getting 200 OK
2. check in the sources tab for the html file
3. if you are using webpack then change the templateUrl to template and use **require** to load the file

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that for some reason your http server can't find template in your working directory.

You can test it directly in browser:

```
<url>/classificationviewer.html
```

And you should see `404 NOT FOUND`, which means that this template was not found.

You said, that your other templates are working great, so you can find where are they located in your working directory and place this one at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your local system directly then does not work. use the angular server load the file
step to solve your problem
1.open cmd prompt and type npm install -g http-server
2.  In cmd type cd (your project folder path) like: cd desktop/app/workout then
3. now in your folder path type http-server -o this command serve your local page on the angular server on your local meachine