# How to set passport token in all header while getting token from the responce angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am working with Angular js and Larvel 5.4.

I have create Login controller for authentication in angular js and its code looks like below :

```
app.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$state) {
$scope.vm.login = function() {

    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl+'auth/token',
            data: $.param($scope.vm.logDetails),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data.access_token);
            if(response.data.access_token) {                    
                $state.go('dashboard.masters_userroles');
            }
            else {
                alert("Your credentials is wrong");
            }
        });
}
});
```

I have created Interceptor for it. But it can not set header.

```
.factory('tokenInjector',function($window){
return {
    //For each request the interceptor will set the bearer token header.
    request: function($config) {            
        if($window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo-token'))
        {
            var token=$window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo-token');
            console.log(token);
            //set authorization header
            $config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
            return $config;
        }
    }
}
})
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('tokenInjector');
})
```

It gives an error like `Error: $compile:tpload Error Loading Template` this.

Here In console I received token in controller. Now I want to set header for all request of **$stateProvider**. So what functionality should I have to create to store token?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27136594/796400

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor How can I set dynamically token?

Comment: dynamically? I couldn't understand. You can use interceptor to set that token to all requests.

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor I have used interceptor but its not working. So procedure should i have to follow? I have updated my question please check it.

Comment: Are you sure that the resources which you are trying to access,before authentication, is not secured? This issue happens when you can't access the template you are passing into your state.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852115/angular-js-error-compiletpload-failed-to-load-template

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the functionality you describe you have to do two things.

1) **Store the token** you've just received in some storage (LocalStorage, SessionStorage, CookieStorage). Anyone you wish.

e.g.

```
sessionStorage.setItem(token, angular.toJson(response.data.access_token));
```

2) For each request you make you have to **provide the stored token in your headers**. For that purpose you might use `$http Interceptors` . You can create a factory for this purpose.

e.g.

```
angular.module('app').factory('tokenInjector',function(){
  return {
    config.headers['Bearer'] = sessionStorage.getItem(angular.fromJson(token));
    return config;
  }
})
```

Then in your `.config` you have to make clear in your app that you want to use your token injector via `$httpProvider` service.

e.g.

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('tokenInjector');
});
```

Comment: It gives an error related to config. I have set token in session and return in factory but it return undefined.